# Is it possible to force functions from one module to honor read-only setting on variables from different module?

Tags: powershell, variables, module, scope

Hi imagine this situation. You have 2 powershell modules as defined bellow.
If you import them to console (just run the code in console), you will be able to use variable test, but not modify it (expected behaviour). But function changeVariable from second module doesnt honor the read only settings and internally can do whatever it wants with variable test.

first module:

```bsh
New-Module {
New-Variable test -Value "test" -Option AllScope, Constant -Force -Scope global

Export-ModuleMember -Variable *
}
```

second module:

```bsh
New-Module {
function changeVariable {
    $test = "someString" # this should end with error, that variable cannot be changed 
    $test
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function *
}
```

So is it possible to create globally non-modifiable variables in powershell?

Comment: Variables default to the current scope. What you're asking is not possible without having the second module (try to) create the variable in the global scope as well (and having the rest of the code explicitly use the variable from the global scope).

Answer (score 1):

The second module is not accessing the `$test` variable from the global scope. It is accessing a variable from the function's scope. You need to indicate that it is a global variable. One way to do this is with the `global` scope modifier.

```
New-Module {
function changeVariable {
    $global:test = "someString" # this should end with error, that variable cannot be changed 
    $global:test
}

Export-ModuleMember -Function *

}
```

There are other scopes available that can be used with the `$[<scope-modifier>:]<name> = <value>` syntax. See [About Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-6).

Comment: OK I get it, but this is not usable solution. I need some general solution instead of rewrite all functions . If it is possible at all. So functions from module behave same as functions defined in console itself.